# How to Append multiple objects in to Nested JSON?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, http-post, angular-promise

> Aim:-   To create Restaurant Business Hours for all days.
>
> Steps I followed :-
>
> 1). Used Post method from service ($http.Post)
>
> 2). Binded UI Elements with ng-model. (
>
> 3). Used Post Method for every Tab
>
> Output :-  Seven Different Objects instead of Nested Json Object .
>
> Could Any one Guys Give me some Ideas Or Sample Code for appending all the  small Jsons in to Nested Json Like Following .

Plunker 
http://plnkr.co/edit/Z7C5CoVDDimKvTHzijgI?p=preview

Outputs:-

```
Actual Ouput Needed.

{
 displayName:"My Restaurnat BusinessHours"
    sun:{
         Opened:true,
         open:"10:00 Am",
         close:"10:00 PM"
          },
    mon:{
         Opened:true,
         open:"10:00 Am",
         close:"10:00 PM"
          },
    tue:{
         Opened:true,
         open:"10:00 Am",
         close:"10:00 PM"
          }

    }

Wrong Out Put :-

{
    displayName:"My Restaurnat BusinessHours"
sun:{
     Opened:true,
     open:"10:00 Am",
     close:"10:00 PM"
      } 
 }


 {
    displayName:"My Restaurnat BusinessHours"
mon:{
     Opened:true,
     open:"10:00 Am",
     close:"10:00 PM"
      } 
 }

 {
    displayName:"My Restaurnat BusinessHours"
tue:{
     Opened:true,
     open:"10:00 Am",
     close:"10:00 PM"
      } 
 }
```

Comment: can you provide the code you re testing?? a fiddle??

Comment: Can you show the actual code of what you have?

Comment: ok sure i can create a fiddle and ping you guys !!

Comment: do you control the api source? Seems like delivering this as array would make more sense

Comment: @charlietfl  no unfortunately. Yes I agree but all these  need to be placed in an Array with Seven Submits

Comment: not totally clear though what expected results are....question is a bit vague. If all you want is to create array loop over object and push each day property to array

Comment: Sure Actually iam creating Plunker with some some sample info ..

Comment: @ Vanojx1 ,@ tymeJV ,@ charlietfl Updated With Plunker Please take a look Actually I got no Privilege to use real Ap'is . Created One Mockup . with actual  and expected outs puts coming.  Please Let me Know if you Have questions

Comment: I found a clue about this issue .. Push Methods  could you guys Know how to Push  json to api end point  instead of Post